# Print fails when using any icc other than default - Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, printing, icc

Epson SC p600 works fine with Default RGB and Default Grey icc profiles.
If any other icc is selected (tried Argyll and proprietary profiles from PermaJet) print is stopped. Job Attributes table shows 
job-printer-state-message Filter failed
and
job-state-reasons job-completed-with-errors

Comment: so this is an airprint compatible printer; and I wonder if that the driver being used: did Ubuntu set this up automatically for you? (Right-click on the p600 icon in the PRINTERS folder and look in MAKE & MODEL .. please tell us). I will put the Epson driver as an answer below

Answer (score 0):

For the Epson driver for this very fine printer,

go here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=62074&DSCCHK=491da99ba16aace3a07d40439367278e7a3319f2 and click to download what for 64bit Ubuntu should be **epson-sc-p9k8k7k6k-ww_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb**

(Epson specifically call this a FULL-FEATURE driver so we hope it is very good)

(I am guessing *ww* means worldwide, as there seem to be specifically japanese drivers further on in the list.

If when one clicks to download, the system offers to "OPEN" the package, accept that as OPEN means install

to set up a printer, one needs to 1) install the drivers and 2) register the printer with LPadmin; ... usually doing 1) seems to trigger an auto 2)

If you now have 2 icons, you need to be able to identify which is the Epson driver

Comment: To pdc - I don't know what an airprint printer is but the Ubuntu autosetup selected a basic Generic Esc/P driver. I changed it to what I believe is the correct one - Epson SureColor P600 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.13. I'll try the driver you suggest and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: I don't think that this is the right driver - it is for the SC6000, 7000, 8000 and 9000.
I have an SC600.
I don't want to risk installing it in case it screws up what I have now, which works, albeit with some workarounds.
Is there another driver for the SC600 please?

Comment: The printer driver listed seems to be for the 6000 rather than the 600.
IIRC the 6000 has more inks as well as a wide carriage.
I'm on the Gutenprint.